# Angular ng-model showing escaped html entities in input

Tags: angularjs, filter, html-entities, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind-html

This is my controller and I added a variable "title" with value "This & That".

```
app.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope){

   $scope.title = "This & That";

}]);
```

My input binds to "title" as below.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title" />
```

The final output is showing below as

"This `&amp;` That" instead of just "This & That".

However if I add a filter like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title | htmlentities_decode" />
```

I get "This & That" but then I can no longer edit the input.

The filter is this

```
app.filter('htmlentities_decode', function(){

    return function(input){

        return $('<textarea />').html(input).text();
    };
});
```

How do I get "This & That" instead of "This `&amp;` That" and still be able to edit the input. Or better, how can I bind title to ng-model and not have the ampersand encoded to `&amp;` without a filter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce). Your code would be like

```
app.filter('htmlentities_decode', function($sce){

    return function(input){
        if(input)
           return $sce.trustAsHtml(input)
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try ng-bind-html instead of ng-model.